# Drawing tables while answering

Tags: discussion, tables

I found table of this kind while surfing for some stuff on Stackoverflow

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║  Col1   ║     col2  ║    col3  ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║       1 ║         3 ║ 6        ║
║       2 ║         1 ║ 1        ║
║       3 ║         1 ║ 2        ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Can anybody tell me How to draw such tables .. ?

Comment: Use [this tool](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Comment: @hims056 thats it thanks a alot..

Comment: i do something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/ztXBS.png its also readable

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Thanks but I know how to create such tables . but have no idea about the one I have asked for